# FormulaR1C1 Dynamic Reference

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem referencing data from Sheet 2 back to Sheet 1 (which is a summary tab).

I want to reference the last row of column A which contains the summation back to cell A1 of Sheet 1, but the problem is that the number of rows differ (as this is dynamic) on every report.

How can i make the following formula dynamic?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet2!R[-23]C"
```

Comment: Could you show some data? You want to reference the last row in sheet 2 or sheet 1? Where are the formulas going? You can get last row with .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row but are you sure you want a fixed number? Would be helpful to see data and expected result.

Comment: So sorry, ok on sheet 1 cell B12 should have the data which is linked to sheet 2 on column h, i designed my macro to automatically sum all the numbers on column h..so the last row would contain the sum formula...i want to link the cell formula to sheet 1 cell B12..the problem is row numbers varies..how do i do this so sorry i dont really speak codes :(

Comment: you want B12 sheet 1 to link to the last populate cell in column H?

Comment: yes thats corect

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").Formula = "=Sheet2!" & .Range("H" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Sheet2! is to make sure the formula references sheet2 when applied in the cell.

Then

```
.Range("H" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
```

finds the last row in column H of sheet 2 by coming up from the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: wow!!! it worked!!! thank you so much!!!, can you explain to me  this? "=Sheet2!" & .Range("H" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Address

Answer (score 1):

Pass the number of rows as a variable like this one:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim numberOfRows As Long

    numberOfRows = -12        
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet2!R[" & numberOfRows & "]C"

End Sub
```

Comment: thnak you for the information please take alook at my comment up,